# Getting Android Icon Position From Chathead

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Currently i have created the chat head using window manager on an android, now i want to drop that chathead over an icon to get information of an app or service running in app.
I want to do the following:-

Get the information about the app on which chat head is dropped.

Get information from within the app on which chat head is dropped.

I have gone thru the manual but it couldn't find the way to implement that.

Comment: "drop that chathead over an icon" -- what icon?

Comment: android app icon, for eg facebook

Comment: And where, exactly, is this icon?

Comment: i wanted to do something like quickactions in the video http://techcrunch.com/2015/09/20/disrupt-sf-2015-hackathon-winners/

Comment: till now i have created an icon that can move with the windowsmanager